# ReactJS: How to use single form in a modal to add multiple rows in a table

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in a modal. I am trying to set states of input fields of form and when the user submits the form that data should be displayed in a table and the same form can be used to add multiple rows in a table.
I have set the initial state inside the constructor as follows

```
product: [{ 
        name: '',
        value:'',
        price:''
}]
```

and on onChange I am doing the following :

```
changeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log('change handler', event)

    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: value
 });
    console.log('product : ', this.state.product)
}
```

The product console is empty. How can I set the state of product?

Comment: because setState is asynchronous function. Try to log it outside of function or with some timeout.

Comment: @demkovych I have tried to log it outside function but it's still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update proper state item:

```
product: [{ 
  name: '',
  value:'',
  price:''
}]

changeHandler = (event, arrayIndex) => {
  const {value, name} = event.target;
  const newData = this.state.product.map((el, idx) => {
    if (idx === arrayIndex) {
      return {
        ...el,
        name: value
      }
    }

    return el;
  });

  this.setState({product: newData});
}
```

Comment: I have set it array because I have to add multiple rows in a table through that form.

Comment: and what's your `event.target.name`?

Comment: it's the name of the input tag.

Comment: is it `product[0]` for first item?

Comment: the problem is that you save state as object but defined as array. You need to setState properly.

Comment: how can i achieve that? I am still confused